# Jacquet-Langlands correspondence for Norm-1-units

Tags: automorphic-forms

Let $M$ be a quaternion algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$, ramified at the set of primes $S$. Let $\pi=\bigotimes_p \pi_p$ be an irreducible, infinite-dimensional subrepresentation of $L^2(M_{\mathbb{A}}^\times)$, where $M_{\mathbb{A}}^\times$ are the units of the adelic points of of $M$.

The Jacquet-Langlands correspondence provides an irreducible, infinite-dimensional representation $\rho=\bigotimes_p \rho_p$ of $GL_2(\mathbb{A})$, such that for all $p\notin S$: $\pi_p \cong \rho_p$.

Is the same result true, if we replace $M_{\mathbb{A}}^\times$ with the adelic norm-1-unit group $M_{\mathbb{A}}^1$ and $GL_2$ with $SL_2$?

Comment: I don't remember the answer on top of my head, but most likely it can be found in Labesse--Langlands "L-Indistinguishability for SL(2)".